Azure Queue Trigger function instantly moving messages to poison queue
So I have quite a basic Azure HTTP function that creates job messages whenever I do a POST request to the url:
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Azure.Storage.Queues;

namespace WeatherImageGenerator.HTTP
{
    public class StartJobFunction
    {

        private readonly ILogger<StartJobFunction> _logger;
        
        public StartJobFunction(ILogger<StartJobFunction> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function("StartJobFunction")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run (
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Received request to start a job.");

                var jobId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

                var message = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { JobId = jobId, Status = "Pending"});

                string connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsStorage");
                QueueClient queueClient = new QueueClient(connectionString, "startjobqueue");

                await queueClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

                await queueClient.SendMessageAsync(message);

                _logger.LogInformation($"Sent message to start job queue for job {jobId}");

                return new OkObjectResult(new { JobId = jobId });
            }
    }
}

However, the moment I add an Azure Queue Trigger to this queue (even with the generated code in VSCode), all messages instantly reach the MaxDequeueCount of 5 and get sent to the poison queue. How can I fix this?
For reference, here's the generated Azure Queue Trigger function:
using System;
using Azure.Storage.Queues.Models;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace WeatherImageGenerator.Queue
{
    public class ProcessStartJobQueue
    {
        private readonly ILogger<ProcessStartJobQueue> _logger;

        public ProcessStartJobQueue(ILogger<ProcessStartJobQueue> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function(nameof(ProcessStartJobQueue))]
        public void Run([QueueTrigger("startjobqueue", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] QueueMessage message)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function started for message: {message.MessageText}");
        }
    }
}

It doesn't even show the queue logger information, just instantly sends messages to the poison queue.

Your issue is with your message encoding.
Older versions of queueClient used to perform encoding automatically, but this is no longer the default behavior as-per documentation here.
Thus, you're going to want to base64encode your string before you send it.
You can do this by using:
var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
var encodedMessage = System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);

and then send the encodedMessage string instead of your original message string.
I suggest creating a static helper method to handle this more easily.
